# Scaling up filtering and function to for loop in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, data.table, tidyverse

This has happened to me multiple times and I want to find an easier way to solve it.

I am creating a function where I want it to loop it for.

Let's say I have the following columns

```
id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4)    
year <- c(2000, 2002, 2004, 
2000, 2002, 2004,
2000, 2002, 2004,
2000, 2002, 2004)
pre.post <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
y <- c(100, 200, 200,
 400, 500, 600,
 700, 800, 300,
 200, 100, 200)

df <- data.frame (id, year, pre.post, y)
```

What I want to do is to have the scale the following code into a function or loop so that I can run it for all values of `year` at once.

This is what I want to do, for every year:

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, fixest)
df%>%
group_by(id)%>%
arrange(year)%>%
  filter(dplyr::lag(pre.post) != 1)%>%
  feols(y ~ pre.post| id + year, data = df, panel.id = ~id+year)
```

Basically, I want R to go into every value of `year` and filter out those  whose lagged `pre.post` is `1` and then run that model.

I tried a lot of different for loops such as the following:

```
  for(i in unique(df$year)) {
  year.df <-  filter(df[year == i, ], lag(pre.post) != 1)
  fixest::feols(y ~ pre.post| ags + year, data = year.df, panel.id = ~ags+year)
}
```

which returns:

```
Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

And other similar things, but I never quite get want I am looking for. The issue is basically with the filtering bit of the loop I think. I also tried to create my own function, which would be even better, but I also not getting it. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(lag(pre.post) != 1) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(test = list(feols(y ~ pre.post| id + year, data = cur_data_all(), 
                        panel.id = ~id+year))) -> result
```

Comment: Yes, it looks good. I think that if I were able to scale that up for every year that'd work. However when I just run it as is it gives me an error from the fixeols function "Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `test`.
x The fixed-effects variable year is not in the data.", which is not true

Comment: Use `cur_data_all()` instead of `cur_data()`.

Comment: Oh now I get a list of results, thanks! My question that I can't quite get right is: is the filter command running for each group separately? Because that's what I was looking for